# Mantener archivos seleccionados en input de tipo file

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire, livewire

estoy hace varios días investigando como puedo mejorar la funcionalidad de carga de imágenes sin resultados.

**Problema:**

1. Al crear el botón de múltiples cargas de imágenes, el usuario puede seleccionar todas las imágenes que desea. Para limitar ese procedimiento a que sólo pueda subir 30 imágenes utilizo max:30 y parece funcionar bien.

Si el usuario hace clic nuevamente sobre el botón reemplaza las imágenes cargadas por las nuevas seleccionada.

Por lo tanto intento crear una funcionalidad que permita agregar más imágenes:

**Mi input:**

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" name="imagenes" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

**Funcionalidad agregar más imagenes:**

```
<button class="text-white btn btn-info btn-sm" wire:click.prevent="add({{$i}})">
     Agregar más fotos
</button>   

@foreach($inputs as $key => $value)        
    <input wire:model="name.{{ $value }}" type="file" name="imagenes" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file">        
@endforeach
```

Lo que necesito es poder validar que no se suban más de 30 imágenes entre los dos input en la vista.

**Validate:**

```
$this->validate([
    'imagenes' => 'max:30',
]);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas declarando en tu componente una propiedad de tipo array que vaya acumulando las imágenes toda vez que tu usuario invoque la función X en el frontend?

Comment: $imagenes es de tipo [], una propiedad aparte te refieres?

Comment: Si, una cosa es la data que te llega y que iteras, pero *propongo* que la clase tenga otra propiedad que acumule por que cada vez quie imagenes es iterada, asumiendo claro que aunque la función sea invocada x cantidad de veces entonces las imágenes sigan ahi

Comment: Me imagino la función pero estoy un poco perdido en el desarrollo. Si tenes un ejemplo te lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que puedes plantearlo de esta forma:

Dentro de tu componente principal, tener:

- 2 propiedades, una que sirve como *binding* entre el `input` y una propiedad del componente y la otra que será el array que almacene los archivos que el usuario va eligiendo

  ```
    public $imagen = [];
    public $imagenes = [];
  ```
- Un método que acumule los archivos recibidos dentro de un array

  ```
    public function cargaImagenes()
    {
        foreach ($this->imagen as $ima) {
            array_push($this->imagenes, $ima);
        } 
    }
  ```
- Un método que tome ese array recién llenado, lo itere y almacene sus valores en una ruta específica

  ```
    public function almacenaImagenes()
    {
        /*
            Tu lógica de iteración y almacenamiento
        */
    }
  ```

Una vez que hemos dividido en 2 métodos distintos las acciones a realizar, entonces debemos igualmente asignar el llamado a estos a 2 elementos HTML.

- Considerando que los *input* de tipo [**`file`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) tienen 2 posibles eventos asociados que son: `change` e `input`, entonces el primer método lo moveremos y haremos que se ejecute precisamente en el *change* de dicho elemento HTML así:

  ```
    <input wire:change="cargaImagenes" type="file" multiple wire:model="imagen">
  ```
- Entonces ahora la lógica de iteración y almacenamiento la asignamos a que ocurra durante el evento `click` del botón de esta forma:

  ```
    <button wire:click="almacenaImagenes">Almacena todo</button>
  ```

Puedes comprobar que el array `$imagenes` va almacenando los archivos que el usuario elige , si en el front imprimes la cantidad de elementos de esta forma:

```
{{ count($imagenes) }}
```

Comment: Te pasaste BetaM muchas gracias!! un lujo tu explicación y la dedicación!!